# Routing loop due to relay emails from lotus domino server

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I want to rout all mails received or send from lotus domino server to an external relay which will do some action and send the mails.

This can be achieved by relaying mails to external servers but when incoming mail is routed it ends up in a loop.

[Similar problem](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21676618#)

Can this be solved by ignoring mail coming from a specific IP . Is there a way to configure emails based on the ip they are received from

Comment: We do exactly the same sort of thing.  Our Domino server sends all outgoing mail to the external relay and delivers all mail for our local domain, abczzz.com to the local inboxes.  The difference is that the external relay is configured to only send mail for abczzz.com to my Domino server.

Comment: Yeah that i have achieved by setting for outbound relay. Problem is that i want to route all the messages, both local mail boxes and internet boxes. Now when mails are delivered to my MTA server i process the mails and send them to the destination. But if mail box is internal it is delivered to Domino and then domino again send the mail to MTA hence loop.